# removing duplicates from list without storing list in memory

Tags: java, performance, scala, out-of-memory

I am trying to find an efficient way to remove duplicate lines from a file without reading the entire contents of the file into memory. The file is randomly ordered. I am trying not to read it into memory because the file is too big (20GB+). Can anyone suggest a way to fix my code so it doesnt read the entire file to memory?

```
val oldFile="steam_out_scala.txt"
val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"

import scala.io.Source
import java.io.{FileReader, FileNotFoundException, IOException}
import java.io.FileWriter;
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

var numbers = new ListBuffer[String]()
val fw = new FileWriter(noDupFile, true) 

for (line <- Source.fromFile(oldFile).getLines()) {
    numbers+=line

}

numbers.distinct.foreach((x)=>{
    //println(x)
    fw.write(x)
})
fw.close()
```

What I know about the data:

each line is a Long ex: 76561193756669631

it is not ordered, and the final result does not need to be ordered in any way

the list was generated using another program. A number could be repeated (0,4million]

Comment: Calculate a hash function (e.g. MD5) to summarize each line and store those in memory.  If a line's hash function is a duplicate, then omit that line.  This will occasionally omit too much but is simple and can be done in one scan of the file.  If the deduplication must not omit unique lines, then add a layer of (slow) double checking.

Comment: What do you know about the numbers in the data file? You can use byte array to represent those numbers and then pass the array once to reconstruct uniques.

Comment: How many duplicates do you expect? I.e. how big will the output file and/or the list of duplicates be?

Comment: Is the order important? If not, sort the file (there are many external sort  algorithms that can sort any size file) then pass through it removing duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can tackle this problem:

1) Read the original file line by line and before adding it to the new file which contains only unique lines check in that file if such a line already exists. This will be pretty slow because `O(n^2)`.

The code would look something like this:

```
val oldFile="steam_out_scala.txt"
val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"

import scala.io.Source
import java.io.{FileReader, FileNotFoundException, IOException}
import java.io.FileWriter;
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

var numbers = new ListBuffer[String]()
val fw = new FileWriter(noDupFile, true) 

for (line <- Source.fromFile(oldFile).getLines()) {
    if(Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().forall(!_.equals(line))) {
        fw.write(line)
    }
}

fw.close()
```

2) You can perform a so called [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) which was invented precisely for sorting large amounts of data that does not fit into memory and is faster than the above method. It sorts small chunks of the whole dataset (which can fit into memory), stores them into temporary files and then merges them together. Fun fact, if your OS has a virtual memory option then the OS will do something similar for you anyway by swapping data that doesn't fit into memory to the hard drive.

Those are generic solutions that will work with any kind of data. If you can provide more information regarding the content of the file we might be able to come up with something more clever.

Comment: Your code solved the problem, but you were right about the time complexity. I tried looking for a simple external sort, but couldnt find an implementation that made sense. Any chance you could explain the concept? Or should that be a new question?

Comment: Did you look at the WIkipedia page @Rilcon42 linked to?

Comment: @Rilcon42 well for the general concept please follow the wikipedia link I posted in my answer. For implementations I have always coded my own just because I find it fun to do but I'm sure if you google `java (or scala) external sort` you'll get some hits (like for instance this https://github.com/grove/exmeso)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bloom filter(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to remove duplication from file